# Google App Engine Eclipse JDO debug connect to deployed datastore

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, jdo

I have a Google App Engine app deployed to App Engine.   Every so often I need to debug some functionality on it.  However, when you debug in Eclipse, it uses a local datastore, and the data is not in sync.  Is it possible to debug in Eclipse locally, (IE using the local jetty server), but connect JDO to the deployed data store? (IE so that i dont have to try to keep my local data store in sync, which would eventually become impossible anyway).

I know about the Remote API, but it seems that is for connecting separate apps?  I want to debug the same code locally that I would then deploy to App Engine. I also can't find anything on how to hook remote api into JDO.

Comment: i never did.  i finally made a routine to sync/replicate the partial data to the local data store. I imagine that re-architecting the solution to use endpoints api (and keep the server-side logic to a minimum) on the GAE might help, but that wont be ideal in all situations.